# How to change Bootstrap's placeholder text with jQuery.on?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i have a `input` with `Bootstrap placeholder` and a `select`. i need that when an `option` selected, the text of placeholder of input changes.

my attempt:

```
$('select').on('change', function ()
{
    $('input').attr('placeholder',$(this).find("option:selected").text())

});
```

Comment: i think that bootstrap.js binds it's objects when page is loaded and after document.ready, changes in those objects will not affect.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code,

```
$('select').on('change', function (){
$('input').attr('placeholder', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: basically not difference between  `$(this).val()` and what i wrote. i think that `bootstrap.js` binds it's objects when page is loaded and after `document.ready`, changes in those objects will not affect.

Comment: ohhhh! i used that input with `id='alert'` this was  my mistake. it's solved!